# Why does Linq know to increment

Tags: linq

I am under the impression, code such as

```
var result = myList.Select(a => a == "Hello")
```

is the same as

```
public string Select(string a)
{
//logic
}
```

Therefore if I did

```
var result = myList.Select((a, v) => a == "Hello")
```

It would 'translate' to

```
public string Select(string a, object v)
{
//logic
}
```

I'm assuming my logic is wrong, because if you consider

```
var index = myList.Select((val, ind) => new { val, ind }).Single(a => a.v.Thing == "Condition").ind;
```

Then this returns the index. It's effectively done

```
public string Select(this List<string> s, string val, int ind)
{
    //for loop, and keep track of the iteration
}
```

But how does Linq know my second value is an iteration? Surely all it knows is that I'm passing 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Select works more like a projection. When you break down your second example, it might get clearer:

```
var index = myList // a list of strings or, more general, an enumerable of string
   .Select((val, ind) => new { val, ind }) // enumerable of anon. type with val and index
   .Single(a => a.v.Thing == "Condition") // any element of enumerable matching condition
   .ind; // the index of this element
```

The second optional parameter is just a counter. If you would do it 'traditionaly' with a for loop it would be your index. This comes in handy sometimes (as in your example) but I rarely use it. See here at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx):

> selector Type: System.Func A transform
>   function to apply to each source element; the second parameter of the
>   function represents the index of the source element.